# iso と img の違いはなんですか？

Tags: バイナリファイル

ディスクイメージのファイルフォーマットとして、.iso が拡張子なものと .img が拡張子なものをよく見かけます。

例：

- .iso: [Ubuntu Desktop 日本語 Remix](https://www.ubuntulinux.jp/download/ja-remix)
- .img: [Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/)

これらはどう違うのでしょうか？

たとえば[英語版 Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMG_(file_format)) には

> ISO images are another type of optical disc image files, which commonly use the `.iso` file extension, but sometimes use the `.img` file extension as well.

と書かれており、とすると同じファイルフォーマットを指していそうな気がするのですが、具体的にこのことを示した規格やマニュアルなどはありますか？　同じページにて .img が他のいくつかのファイルフォーマットの拡張子としても使われているようにとれる記述もあり、やや混乱しています。たとえば自分でディスクイメージを作る際、拡張子を選ぶ参考になるような情報が欲しいです。

追記：なるべく出典が欲しいです。Wikipedia の記事もいくつか見たのですが、特に img ファイルについてなかなかコレといった出典がありませんでした。歴史的経緯により成り立っていったファイルフォーマットということであればなかなか出典となるような文献を見つけるのが難しいのかもしれません……。

Answer (score 3):

規格があるかは確認できてないですが、一般的には

- `.iso`の拡張子のファイルは、CDROM、DVDROM等、光学メディアのイメージファイル
- `.img`の拡張子のファイルは、SDカード、USBディスク等、ディスクのイメージファイル

という使い分けになっていると思います。

---

`.iso`については、[英語版WikipediaのISO image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image)の
ページに説明があります。

Wikipediaより引用:

> An ISO image is a disk image of an optical disc. In other words, it is an archive file that contains everything that would be written to an optical disc, sector by sector, including the optical disc file system.
>    ISO image files bear the `.iso` filename extension.

＃歴史的経緯から予想すると、[`mkisofs`のマニュアル](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkisofs)の実行例で、出力ファイル名を「`cd.iso`」と記載していたので、慣用的に広まったものと思います。

マニュアルより引用:

> To create a vanilla ISO-9660 filesystem image in the file cd.iso, where the directory cd_dir will become the root directory if the CD, call:
>
> `% mkisofs -o cd.iso cd_dir`

---

一方、`.img`ファイルは、[英語版WikipediaのIMG(file format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMG_(file_format))には、「元々フロッピーディスクイメージファイルの拡張子」と記載があります。

Wikepediaより引用:

> The `.img` file extension was originally used for floppy disk raw disk images only.

ただ、フロッピーディスクは使われなくなったため、現在は「raw disk images」の意味合いが流用されて、起動可能なディスクイメージファイル全般を指すようになっていると思います。

Answer (score 0):

.iso は ISO9660 を意味していると思います。
.img は デバイスのバイト列をそのままファイルに書き込んだ イメージファイルのことだと思います。

> とすると同じファイルフォーマットを指していそうな気がするのですが

UNIX系のシステムでは拡張子にはほとんど意味がありませんので、単なるファイル名の一部だと思ってください。したがって 拡張子で判断することは出来ません。

ただ、.img は何かしらのデバイスのイメージファイルと言う意味で、より広義の捉え方が出来ますので、そういった解釈も成り立つと思います。

Answer (score -1):

- ISO ファイルは国際標準化機構 (ISO) の定義した **光学メディア向け** のアーカイブフォーマット。
- IMG ファイルはフロッピーディスクに始まるバックアップを単一のファイルにまとめるためのフォーマット。現在はハードディスクなどのイメージファイル作成にも使用される。

ISOはCDなどの光学ディスクをまとめたもの、IMGは(CD含めた)より広い範囲のバックアップイメージ、といった印象です。

質問に書かれているUbuntu等のディストリビューションは基本的にCD/DVDに焼き付ける事を前提としたISOイメージを配布しますが、Raspbian等のRasPi向けディストリビューションは **SDカード** を使用するため、IMGファイルとして配布しているのではないでしょうか。

なお、最近のUbuntuはUSBにも直接書き込める "ハイブリッドISO" という形式を採用しています。

また、IMGファイルについては [参考サイト](https://ja.computersm.com/36-what-are-the-differences-between-iso-and-img-files-41625) に以下のような記述もありました。

> ISOフォーマットには1つのバージョンしかありませんが、IMGには2つのバージョンがあります。
>   圧縮と非圧縮です。

**参考:**
[ISOイメージ - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8)
[ISOファイルとIMGファイルの違いは何ですか？](https://ja.computersm.com/36-what-are-the-differences-between-iso-and-img-files-41625)

Comment: 参考サイトは https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-are-the-differences-between-iso-and-img-files の無断翻訳でYouTubeの再生誘導を目的としたものと思われます。元サイトにはYouTube動画は含まれていません。